# Class template argument dependent on constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

With a templated number wrapping struct:

```
template <int I> struct Num { static const int n = I; };
```

and a few overloaded functions:

```
template <typename T>
Num<0> id(T x)      { return Num<0>(); }
Num<1> id(int x)    { return Num<1>(); }
Num<2> id(double x) { return Num<2>(); }
Num<3> id(char x)   { return Num<3>(); }
```

I can initialise the `m_i` member of a `Zod` struct using `decltype` and the type of the return argument of `id`:

```
template <typename T>
struct Zod {
  Zod(T x) { m_i = identity<decltype(id(x))>::type::n; }
  int m_i;
};
```

However, what I'd really like is for the `Zod` struct to have a second integer template argument initialised to the value which `m_i` was set to.

```
template <typename T, int I = ?>
struct Zod { ... }
```

This seems possible, as the `identity`/`decltype` expression evaluates to a compile time constant; for example, this is fine at global scope:

```
char c;
static const int g = identity<decltype(id(c))>::type::n;
```

The problem is that the `x` argument of the constructor is not available in the scope of `Zod`'s template declaration. Can it be done?

Comment: I suppose making `m_i` static const is not an option ? What do you want to achieve, out of curiosity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly possible- just pass in `*((T*)nullptr)` to obtain an lvalue of any type T regardless of it's constructability. After all, all you actually do with the constructor argument is pass it to `id` and then `decltype` that, which is perfectly doable in the template, since you know that the type of `x` is `T`.

```
template<typename T, int I = identity<decltype(id(*((T*)nullptr)))>::type::n> struct Zod {
    ...
};
```

Comment: Aaah! I've been trying to construct a problem that *needs* to use a value in the way I outlined. Likely it doesn't exist.